# Tapku Calendar demo does not work in xCode4/iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, tapku

I installed xCode 4 and iOS 5 today.

I have used the Tapku library in the past so i went a downloaded it: https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary

I opened the demo in xCode and am running the calendar demo on the iPhone iOS5 simulator and it is crashing right away. Am i doing something wrong?

Debugging the TKCalendarMonthView.m class i find the error is related to monthDate in the dateSelected function.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Devin, the creator of Tapku. It turns out the code had a error in it. He fixed it and uploaded a fixed version.

Comment: hello @Mausimo , where he has uploaded it , I have also tried it from git hub demo but it is not working... a lot of error displays